# How to animate my header (reduce its height) as i scroll through my Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-animation, react-animated

can you see what i'm doing wrong here in animating my flatlist?

The `this.animatedHeaderHeight` picks up my start and end header height fine, but when i scroll up and down in the flatllist, the header doesn't change it's height whatsoever! Help!

```js
export default class MyClass extends Component {

  componentWillMount = async () => {
    /***** Animated scrolling hide profile info ****/
    this.scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
    this.startHeaderHeight = 250 //(ITEM_HEIGHT/4)
    this.endHeaderHeight = 50 //(ITEM_HEIGHT/7)
    this.animatedHeaderHeight = this.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 50],
      outputRange: [this.startHeaderHeight, this.endHeaderHeight],
      extraploate: 'clamp'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.profileContainer}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.HeaderArea, { height: this.animatedHeaderHeight, backgroundColor: 'orange' }]}>
          <View style={styles.uploaderPic}>
            <Text> HELLO </Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
        <View style={styles.grid}>
          <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}>
            <FlatList
              numColumns={columns}
              data={myArray}
              onScroll={Animated.event(
                [
                  { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } },
                  { useNativeDriver: true }
                ]
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => { return index }}
              renderItem={...}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profileContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  HeaderArea: {},
  uploaderPic: {},
  grid: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
});
```